# Calculate the convolution of the product of a unit step function and t. (5.6-14)

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, solution-verification, convolution

**Request**

Please check my work. I am not certain how to calculate the convolution of the unit step function.

**Given**:

Find the convolution of $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=u(t-1)$.

$$h(t)=(f*g)(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$$

**My Solution**:

When $0<t<1$, $u(t-1)=0$ and when $t>1$, $u(t-1)=1$. We shall solve for $t>1$.

$$h(t)=t*1=\int_1^t 1\cdot (t-\tau) d\tau=\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$$

**Answer**

When $0<t<1$, $h(t)=0$

When $t>1$, $h(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}$

**Question**

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution isn't correct. The integral is
\begin{align}
\int_1^t(t - \tau)d\tau &= t\tau - \tau^2/2\Bigr|_1^t\\
&=t^2-t^2/2-t+1/2=\frac{t^2}{2}-t+\frac{1}{2}\\ 
&= \frac{(t-1)^2}{2}
\end{align}
You marked this post as a Laplace transform. Are we supposed to also take the transform of the convolution?

Comment: Thank you for checking this for me. Ahh I see the error was just a glitch in the last step of solving the definite integral. So I guess I can conclude that my methodology for taking the convolution of a unit step function was correct. That is what I was really concerned with.

Comment: @JulesManson good to see that you understand.